# How to create custom dialog common method for entire android app using java?

Tags: android, android-activity, customdialog

I am custom dialog in every activity write custom dialog code.How to write common method passing two parameters context and message string?please give me any suggestion.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this,R.style.DialogTheme);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.notify_received_activity);
// set the custom dialog components - text and button
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
text.setText("Tracking Number : " + mTrackingNR);
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {dialog.dismiss();} });
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  /**
         * Display Dialog
         **/
        public static void showDialog(final Context context, String message) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.DialogTheme);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.notify_received_activity);
    // set the custom dialog components - text and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
    text.setText(message);
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {dialog.dismiss();} });
    dialog.show();
        }
```

and simply call anywhere as below:

```
showDialog(ActivityName.this,"message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to do:

```
    public static void showAlert(Context context, String message)
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            TextView messageTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogMessageTextView);
            messageTextView.setText(message);
            Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogOkButton);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                });
            dialog.show();
        }
```

The tricky part is if you want the action `dialog.dismiss()` every time the user clicks an ok button.

Where you need a custom implementation depending on the dialog, you will have to write code for that dialog separately.

Can call this method by passing the `context` from where ever you are calling.

Can be declared in a normal java class, need not be an activity. eg. `Utility.showAlert(activityContext, "your message or variable");`

Answer (score 0):

How is specified in the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), you can pass arguments to a dialog in the following way...

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    int mNum;   

   /**
    * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing its arguments
    */
   static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num, /*other parameters*/) {
      MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("num", num);
    //put all parameters on the Bundle
      f.setArguments(args);

      return f;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
    //get the arguments
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //create the view

       return v;
  }
}
```